# How to download comments in instaloader

Tags: python, instagram, instaloader

I want to download only comments to all posts. How can i do this?
Now I'm downloading json files, images for posts and descriptions.
but I probably only need json files to extract comments from there.

[image]

Comment: you need to give an example json, and excepted part of that json

Comment: Please post the code as a text, ant an screenshot.